# How to reduce Inventory in sheet1("stock") on the bases of product sold in sheet2("sales") through google sheets script...?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets for inventory management, `sheet1` is stock in which Product and Quantity are mentioned, `sheet2` is the sale of the day. I want to automatically deduct stock when a product is written over there, if apple is sold, then it should automatically deduct one quantity from sheet1. 
The sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l8DCQY1DiWSJFevR3J8Ac4Rv5jXQum-EV1QaPwH64a8/edit?usp=sharing).

Some code like this:

```
function onedit(sheet2,A2) {
    if the product in Sheet2!A2 is in Sheet1!A2:A,Subtract 1 from Sheet1!B2:B
}
```

Comment: You can certainly express this in JavaScript. See https://yagisanatode.com/2017/11/03/can-i-modify-google-sheets-with-code/ for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cell `B2`, you can insert this formula:

```
= 4 - SUM(QUERY(sold!$A$1:B, 
 "select count(A) 
  where A = '" & A2 & "' 
  group by A", false))
```

Then, you can drag it down to let the formula apply to all your rows.

The formula counts the number of occurrences in the "sold" sheet of the term in the column A of the first sheet. The `QUERY` function returns a table with one column and two rows (header and data). the `SUM` is applied to it, and reduces the QUERY result to a single number.

As with all formulas, results are kept up to date by the Google sheet automatically.

Instead of having the initial inventory in the formula itself, I suggest to use a separate column, for example column C. The formula above would then start with `C2` instead of 4.

Comment: Thanks @Gogowitsch, i've updated Sheet as suggested by you. now we have 4 columns: Product, Quantity, Sold, Balance. but if Banana is not sold, formula in Sold(C) was subtracting '0' from Quantity(B), and thus showing the '0' as Balance(D). So, updated formula: = if(SUM(QUERY(sold!$A$1:B, 
 "select count(A) 
  where A = '" & A5 & "' 
  group by A")) = 0,0,B5- SUM(QUERY(sold!$A$1:B, 
 "select count(A) 
  where A = '" & A5 & "' 
  group by A",False))).Big Thanks to you.:)

Comment: Good to know I could help you. Please accept my answer and vote it up, so I'll get credit for it. Thanks in advance :-)